# How to find the domain and range of $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-2x+5}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

This is the function:

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-2x+5}$$

Edit: normally what I would do is this: Since it's a square root function, the thing inside the root has to be $\ge 0$. So, $(x^2 - 2x+5)\ge 0$. Then I would factor the stuff in the brackets so that I get (**) (__**). But since this has complex roots, I don't know what to do

Edit: Thanks for the help with the domain! For the range, I found the inverse of the function and did this:

$$x = \sqrt{(y-1)^2 +4}$$ 
$$x^2 -4 = (y-1)^2 $$
$$\sqrt{x^2 -4}+1 = y$$

And then proceeded to find the domain of the inverse:

$$x^2 -4 \ge 0$$
$$x^2 \ge 4$$
$$x \ge  +-2$$

Is this correct? How do I know if it is correct without graphing it out?

Comment: $x^2 - 2 x + 5 = (x-1)^2 + 4$

Comment: What are your thoughts about it? Show us some previous work you have done on this problem so we can help you better.

Comment: (to continue Dmoreno's comment) For example, you could reassure us that you know what the teminologies "domain" and "range" mean.

Comment: Okay, so normally what I would do is this:
Since it's a square root function, the thing inside the root has to be >=0. 

So, (x^2 - 2x+5) >= 0. Then I would factor the stuff in the brackets so that I get (_____) (_______). But since this has complex roots, I don't know what to do

Comment: That's precisely the sort of thing we're looking for. Why not edit the original question to include this information?

Comment: You absolutely should draw a graph!!

Comment: But is there another way to know without graphing? Because we're not always allowed to have graphing calculators with us for quizzes. @WillJagy

Comment: Yes, there is another way. Go back to Adi Dani's hint: the expression inside the square root is $x^2 - 2x + 5 = (x - 1)^2 + 4$. This takes on a minimum value of $4$ when $x = 1$. Therefore the minimum value of the square root is $\sqrt{4} = 2$, so you are quite correct that the range is $x \geq 2$.

Comment: Oops, that was sloppy of me, thanks. The range consists of all real numbers greater than or equal to $2$, but I should not have expressed it using $x$. Better to write $[2,\infty)$.

Comment: NOT graphing calculator. Human being and graph paper, which has little squares on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:$$x^2-2x+5=(x-1)^2+4\geq0$$ for all$x\in(-\infty,+\infty)=\mathbb R$

Comment: Fine now. Just sayin

Comment: factoring is wrong. the roots are actually $1 \pm 2i$

Comment: I edit my answer

Comment: But how did you go from that step to finding out that the domain is all real numbers? I understand that you completed the square, but I don't get how you jumped from that to the domain...

Comment: What the hint shows is that the expression inside the square root is positive for any $x$, so you can take the square root for any $x$. So the domain is...?

Comment: Expression under square root is always positive

Comment: I'm going to nitpick here, the expression on the right hand side is strictly greater than zero, not greater than or equal to.

Answer (score 0):

> I found the inverse of the function ... And then proceeded to find the domain of the inverse

I understand the logic of doing this when finding the range, since range is kind of the  domain of inverse function... provided there **is** an inverse function. Not every function has an inverse: if several values of $x$ correspond to the same $y$, we cannot invert this relationship.

Since the range concerns the values of dependent variable ($y$ in your case), it helps to look at a formula where $y$ is isolated -- which it was from the beginning, 
$y = \sqrt{x^2-2x+5}$. We want to know what kind of values this square root can produce. That depends on what goes under the square root, of course. Under the square root we have $x^2-4x+5 = (x-1)^2+4$. So, this is something that takes on all values from $4$ upward, and none below $4$. So you consider what sort of square root comes out of this, and arrive at the answer for the range.